# Is there anyway to limit/restrict wifi access?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Where I live, internet is pretty bad. Nothing over 30mbps available. It's also very erratic varying from >1mbps to the max at various times in the day.

But the thing I need help with, is on top of that, in my house there's a foreign tv box that uses the internet to watch asian television. I've check and that thing has a crazy buffering system, usually never stops. So whenever it's active, the internet kinda just becomes unusable for me.
So to help alleviate this, I would like lower its queue in the router's system, or just limit its bandwidth, or just be able to deny/re-grant access to it from my laptop.

I'm the 'admin' so to speak of my house's router. So I alone have access to the router page.
I can remotely change the password, ssid , etc. But can't seem to figure out how to do this.
It's an at&t 3801hgv if that helps.

I'm open to anything at this point. Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a localized question. The hardware appears to be a very old router that was never a final product. I would call At&T support for help as they provide your Internet and the router.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to be able to deny/grant access, the easiest thing to do would be to set up a MAC filter rule for that specific device that you can turn on or off depending on when you need it. I don't see any info on layer7 shaping in your manual (provided below) or on bandwidth caps per device. There is however the option to put local devices on an access schedule (so it could run only at night when no one else is online, pg 22-23)

http://www.danwilsonsoftware.com/dl/3800HGV-B.Manual.pdf

Comment: Wow, thanks for the manual, but it's not the same. Mine's one generation (?) newer and also At&t-nized. Idk what you call the config page, but that one has Att logos slapped all over it.

Answer (score 0):

While your router looks quite powerful, from the specs I suspect it may be unable to do what you need.  A solution might be to use it only as a dumb modem and connect it to an ethernet router which is capable of running DD-WRT or similar.  (So you would turn off the WIFI AP on it and simply plug it into a device flashed to run DD-WRT.  If you are sophisticated you would set up routing so as not to do double-nat, but that is not neccessary to make things work).

It sounds to me like you need to configure QoS and possibly also Time-of-day routing.  Bandwidth limiting is certainly another tool.

Comment: Or any modern router for that matter. A slightly messier option, though cheaper would be to get a wifi dongle that acts as an AP, and connect the router through that.